# Build a library like jQuery, html2canvas

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, module, shared-libraries

I have to build a simple javascript library to convert html to pdf and image using html2canvas and jsPDF but I don't know how to do.

I just wrote a simple js file (htmlPrinter.js) to test with simple example and when using I have to load html2canvas and jsPDF in html file. (See following code)

The problems are:

- I have to change my htmlPrinter.js become a node module and require html2canvas and jsPDF, right? (it doesn't work at client-side)
- And then how to make it become a library like jQuery? (Make my htmlPrinter.js become htmlPrinter.min.js, don't have to load html2canvas and jsPDF in html file, work ok with Angular)
- I tried to coppy and paste html2canvas.min.js and jsPDF.min.js into htmlPrinter.js but it didn't work with Angularjs. (I know it's a stupid way)

Thanks all.

```
htmlPrinter = {

toIMG: function(html, width, height){
    html2canvas(html , {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
           document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
},
toPDF: function (html){ 

    html2canvas(html, {        
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            var imgWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width; 
            var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;   
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            var heightLeft = imgHeight;
            var position = 0;
            var image= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            doc.addImage(image, 'PNG', 10, 10 , imgWidth-20, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight-10 ;

            while (heightLeft > 0) {
               position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
               doc.addPage();
               doc.addImage(image, 'PNG',10, position, imgWidth-20, imgHeight);
               heightLeft -= pageHeight;
            }

            doc.save('test.pdf')

        },

    });



}
```

}

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do... You want to make a client side or server side library ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a client-side library.